# Python Twisted TLS connection with STARTTLS and authentication - error in example code?

Tags: python, authentication, ssl, twisted

I've been trying to create a simple python twisted TLS client/server application based on https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/core/howto/ssl.html#client-authentication and https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/core/howto/ssl.html#using-starttls. Ie, I want to create a plain text connection, then on client issue of a STARTTLS command, switch to a secure connection, with the appropriate certificate authentication. So far, I've had little joy.

My first concern is the client auth example in the URL above is wrong. This seems to suggest the client and server *both* need "server.pem" (private key and self-signed certificate together) and "public.pem" (the server’s public certificate by itself). My understanding of authentication is that if the client has the server's private key, then this renders the authentication / security largely redundant? Assuming I'm right, how *should* this example look?

Secondly, as much as I've tried - I'm still struggling to get my head around the way Twisted works generally. Can someone give some illustration to how amend the starttls example in the URL above to incorporate authentication?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first concern is the client auth example in the URL above is wrong. This seems to suggest the client and server both need "server.pem" (private key and self-signed certificate together) and "public.pem" (the server’s public certificate by itself). My understanding of authentication is that if the client has the server's private key, then this renders the authentication / security largely redundant? Assuming I'm right, how should this example look?

The URL you linked to is the "Client Authentication" section of the TLS documentation.  It is demonstrating how you use a client-side certificate to authenticate the client to the server (note that what is common with TLS - HTTPS - is to authenticate the server to the client).

In the case of client authentication, the client does indeed need a private key and a certificate (self-signed or otherwise).  This parallels the requirement that in "normal" TLS (where only the server authenticates itself to the client) the server must have a private key and a certificate (self-signed or otherwise).

The client does not need the *server's* private key, though.  It needs its own.  (Actually, it will work if both sides have the same key, but this isn't the typical case.)

> Secondly, as much as I've tried - I'm still struggling to get my head around the way Twisted works generally. Can someone give some illustration to how amend the starttls example in the URL above to incorporate authentication?

What kind of authentication do you want?  If you're doing TLS client authentication, then that is a form of authentication.  If that is sufficient, you just need to configure your server properly.  The same certificate validation logic that clients normally do for the server certificate presented is done - but in the opposite direction - when you use a client certificate.  The server looks for a chain if valid signatures from the certificate to one of its trust roots.

Comment: I spoke to a colleague about how our existing system works: "mail server attempts to start a TLS session client/svr exchange certs, openssl takes care of the validation, ie has the certificate expired, is it signed by a recognised CA. You will need to pass the python code three things: CA certs file (list of all the agencies that can sign certs), public key file (exchanged with the mail server as part of the SSL handshake), and the private key (used internally to say its allowed to use the public key). We may also want to validate that the key belongs to the server. Thanks @Jean-PaulCalderone

Comment: Presumably the client validates the server's certificate (using OpenSSL).  Does the client also present a certificate for the server to validate, though?  I don't think this is common so it seems unlikely that it's what you're looking for.  If it *is* what you want, then what the example you linked to does is basically correct.  If it is *not* what you want, then you can replace `ssl.PrivateCertificate.options(...)` with something like `ssl.CertificateOptions(verify=True, caCerts=[CA certs])` - but read the API docs for `CertificateOptions` and maybe also for `SSL4ClientEndpoint`.

Comment: Note that Twisted recently got some better APIs for certificate validation.  `CertificateOptions` is still the underlying thing but some of the higher-level APIs take care of some of the security steps for you so you don't have to worry about getting as many complicated crypto/security things right (particularly where there is only one right answer).

Comment: Thanks again @Jean-PaulCalderone ... Looking at the docs one of the changes to CertificateOptions you mention seems to include "trustRoot" - favoured ahead of verify / cacerts. I'm definitely understanding more now... learning slowly! What I'm trying to do now is work out how to put this into the starttls_server.py (our server needs to support both plain text, and TLS connections). I'll have a wrestle with it a while, then maybe raise a fresh q (don't want to go off topic from here!). THANK YOU AGAIN :)